# Barely Used Car in Summer with Winter Tyres

Tags: tires, winter

Is it OK to leave winter tires on in 20 C temperature, for 2 months, assuming the car will be making 50 km per week only?

There are lots of sources explaining you should not drive in hot weather but they don’t explain if it’s OK if you are driving barely or not at all.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the answers. Someone asked me to clarify what do I mean by "OK": I meant whether it is economically rational, e.g. I'm not ruining my tires just because they sit in 20 C on a not moving car, right? Other than that, I know it's not wise to actively use the car without replacing with summer tires. And I don't care the legal stuff.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "OK". Do you mean legally (certain countries have laws on changing), safety-wise (I don't believe winter tyres will be a problem, but I don't even have a driver's license) or financially (my understanding is that winter tires get worn down more easy, so you'll end up spending more money on tires).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I know there are places where winter tyres are mandatory in winter.  I'm now aware of anywhere where it's forbidden to run them in summer

Comment: Probably needs to specify the location (country and eventually state) as there may be local rules which apply.

Comment: @ChrisH - back in the 70s/80s where I lived, a 'snow tire' meant it had metal studs. There were limits to when those were legal to have on your car since they did more damage to the roads.

Comment: @JonCuster they still exist, but I've never driven on them (I have some for my bicycle though).  They're not what are generally referred to as "winter" tyres, in terms of the laws in e.g. Germany, instead "studded" is the common term. I can't tell which continent the OP is on, but "km" suggests Europe or Canada

Comment: 20 °C are not hot weather

Comment: @ChrisH - indeed, they were studded, but that was pretty much the default 'winter tire' - these days tires are much much better (all around), and front wheel drive is much less demanding on what tires are needed in snow. I don't miss the days of having to swap tires, store them, etc., much less the annoying rumble of studs on bare pavement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unless the tires are studded, it's perfectly legal in almost all legislations. Check your local rules for details.
2. Winter tires wear out more quickly then summer tires in warm weather.

If you don't drive a lot, don't live in a climate with excessively hot summers, and if you don't drive aggressively, this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

The question is addressed on a [Bridgestone web site](https://www.bridgestonetire.com/learn/tire-technology/driving-winter-tires-year-round/). If you only drive a small amount in the warm weather, the faster wear won't be an issue for you. But in warm weather, on wet or dry roads, standard tires provide better handling and shorter stopping distances than winter tires. One collision costs more than a few sets of tires. If you don't survive the collision, you won't have to worry about the cost of tires.